# How do I type text on top of a PDF?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I've been given a form to fill out as a PDF.  It is not a fillable PDF, it's just a file that I'm expected to print out, fill in by hand, and scan back in.  Is there something available in the software center that will let me type text on top of a PDF?

Comment: Try [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/16652/62688

Comment: Nobody seems to know fillable PDFs even exist ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lots of resources on the web recommend `pdfedit` but that's not available in the latest ubuntu.  `xournal` works perfectly for this.

Answer (score 2):

(I really hate when people answer as a comment, so I'm going to list Inkscape here as an alternative and flag the comment.)

Typically I prefer `inkscape` to `gimp` (Gimp is very clunky to use), but both are limited to a single page at a time.  Thus if you have more than one page to edit, you'll need a tool like pdf-Shuffler to recombine the individual pdf files.

This limitation is why I decided to look for another editor, and am happy to report that John Baber's answer of using `xournal` worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wikihow.com/Edit-PDF-Files-in-Linux-Using-GIMP

requires both GIMP and Krita but it does work

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I spent lots of time trying them all and see which one was best for my need and easy fast to learn.

I strongly advise you to try PDF-XChange Viewer over wine, it runs smoothly and will probably do all you need. [Here](http://www.fsavard.com/flow/2009/03/pdf-annotation-under-linux-with-wine-and-pdf-xchange-viewer/) are some tips.

[A review of other PDF editors, XChange included](http://www.gnurou.org/blog/2008/09/09/finally_real_pdf_annotating_under_linux)