# What free PDF editing software packages are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which programs can I use to edit PDF files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16652/which-programs-can-i-use-to-edit-pdf-files)

I'm looking for a free PDF editor that will allow me to selectively delete pages and content, including selective parts of a specific page (the use case: reading a large documentation PDF. Need to cut down the noise by deleting stuff that I identify as not relevant).

Does anyone know of such a tool?