# What freely available software is equipped for editing PDF Bookmarks?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, pdf-bookmarks

I know of PDFMod, which I rather like except it has one flaw, I can't seem to be able to add bookmarks before pre-existing bookmarks (see the attached image if this is unclear). [image]

I've looked at this question:
 - [Which programs can I use to edit PDF files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16652/which-programs-can-i-use-to-edit-pdf-files)

That question does not deal specifically with bookmark editing, neither does it specify which software is freely available and which isn't.

I should add that I'm incompetent when it comes to installing software so any software that's not available in the Software Centre requires you to detail exactly how I'm meant to install it. Plus, I would specifically like a software that can handle large (like >80 MB) PDF files without lagging like crazy or closing down.

Comment: It was. Albeit, I am grateful he/she reopened my question at least, unlike that other moderator that just closed it without a second thought.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - yours was not an answer - it was more of a comment.  If you either create a new answer or edit your existing answer expanding the answer to showing Master MDF editor actually demonstrating the OP's question then great.  If you look at the question the OP requests how to install - you havent covered the other parts of the question as well.  Remember we are looking for canonical type answers - one line comments rarely make good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Foxit Reader 6](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/)
- [JPDFbookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/2008/07/jpsdbookmarks-download-page.html)
- [PdfWriteBookmarks](https://github.com/goerz/pdfWriteBookmarks)

Comment: How do I install JPDFboomarks?

Comment: Download and extract the binaries in .tar.gz format  then follow instructions in the README .